# Using ML to create unique descriptors?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I have a problem that doesn't seem to fall into a common machine learning category, and I was wondering if this still could potentially be solved with ML.

Problem: I have two signals recorded from two sensors, and would like to determine whether they are correlated (i.e. record the same physical event) or not.

**The catch**: I don't have access to the full signal time series of both sensors, but only one at a time - I can only exchange a small descriptor on the order of 32 bits to see if the signals match or not.

Our current approach is to calculate a bunch of numerical signal features such as mean, derivative, zero-crossings, FFT etc. and see which ones provide the best correlation - but that seems to be a lot of guesswork and doesn't work very well in any case.

So now I had the following idea:

1. Start with a neural network which takes a fixed window out of the signal (+ possibly the FFT of that window) as an input, and produces a 32-bit output
2. Pick two random correlated samples out of the pool of examples, and run the network ***twice***, once with each sample (and its FFT)
3. Take the ***difference*** between the two output values as error measure and perform backpropagation as usual
4. Repeat from 2. until the difference for all examples is below a threshold

Here are my questions:

1. Does this approach seem feasible at all?
2. As someone relatively new to machine learning, how would I implement this?
3. I've had a look at Keras - would this be a suitable starting point?

Thanks in advance, and best regards, Florian

Addendum: I've found this somewhat related post ([Is it possible using tensorflow to create a neural network that maps a certain input to a certain output?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/14503/is-it-possible-using-tensorflow-to-create-a-neural-network-that-maps-a-certain-i)), but I don't think that this is the same problem, as I don't actually care what the output looks like, just that it is as unique as possible for each matching pair of samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly your question, you want a function that takes a signal (a fixed window) and outputs a 32-bit representation in a way that the correlation between it and any other signal is preserved. Mathematically speaking given signals $s_1$ and $s_2$ in $S$ and a correlation function $corr(s_1, s_2)$ you want some function $f : S \rightarrow B$ (where $B$ is the space of 32-bit binary numbers) that you could use another correlation function for instance $corr_f(b_1, b_2) \approx corr(s_1, s_2)$.

If that is what you want you should at hashing techniques in particular [learning to hash](https://cs.nju.edu.cn/lwj/L2H.html). Essentially in hashing want you do is you represent your input by binary numbers in a way that the [hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) between the binary numbers preserves some target similarity (distance) function such as the correlation. In particular for cross-correlation (inner product) you have some methods based on [random projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing#Random_projection).

So once you have learned (designed) your hashing function $f$, what I would do is:

```
b1 = f(s1)
send b1
receive b1
b2 = f(s2)
return h(b2, b1) # this value is going to tell you if the signals are correlated
```

Comment: Many thanks for the pointer. After reading the introduction, I think that "DPSH: Feature learning based deep supervised hashing with pairwise
labels" might be more or less exactly what I was thinking about. I'll have a closer look.

Comment: I've browsed through the paper, and the core idea is indeed exactly the same as in my original question. Beautiful :-) Thanks again for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, the paper referred to from the comments above ("DPSH: Feature learning based deep supervised hashing with pairwise labels") is available on arXiv: https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.03855
The paper applies the same idea to images, but the principle is more or less exactly identical to my original proposal.